# what are all the essential things to change in IIS 7 to make the web application speedup?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, web-deployment

We are developed asp.net (.net 4 framework) web application and deployed in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.But when we host the web application on our IIS 5.1 server on my local machine ie,windowsxp machine it seems to be work faster than one deployed in the Windows Sever 2008 machine.

most probably the most number of user access the web application at the same is approximately 50 only... Do i need to change any setting in application pool on IIS7.

When deploying i have never changed any settings in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.I have deployed using Visual Studio 2010 support.

I don't know about the reason why it is acting like this?

So, Could you please tell me what are all the essential things do i need to change in IIS 7 and also Windows Server 2008 to speedup my web application...

Answer (score 1):

Increase the worker process number in application pool such that it matches the processor cores (tetra core / penta core) in your windows-server machine so that it could make use of server effectively. But keep in mind, you have to choose `SessionState` other than `In-Proc` in your application if you increase your worker process number.

Comment: Thanks and that one is enough ah?

Comment: Am not sure if its the only way. Other ways might be there too.

Comment: i hope this link [Tips for Windows Server 2008 and IIS7 Tuning](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2010/01/04/3718.aspx) might help you in tuning up Windows Server 2008 and IIS7.